# Connect to a local SQL Server db with sequelize

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

Having completed the SQL Server installer, the given connection string is `Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;`, which seems like a strange format, and if I try to connect to the db with sequelize using that connection string:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_STRING);
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
>
> at new Sequelize
>   (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\TestProj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:132:40)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\TestProj\models\index.js:13:21) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

Comment: Related for PostgreSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207155/sequelize-and-peer-authentication-for-postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8) you should install [`sequelize-msnodesqlv8`](https://github.com/ratanakvlun/sequelize-msnodesqlv8/blob/master/package.json):

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectModulePath: 'sequelize-msnodesqlv8',
  dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVER01',
    trustedConnection: true
  },
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'master'
});
```

or perhaps better:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectModulePath: 'sequelize-msnodesqlv8',
  dialectOptions: {
    connectionString: 'Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=master; Trusted_Connection=yes;'
  },
});
```

But you should not leave default database as `Master`. Use your database name instead.

Mark this:

> There are many node mssql clients and sequelize defaults to using
>   tedious, but being pure javascript,tedious **lacks support for
>   integrated security**. msnodesqlv8 is a client that interfaces with a
>   native odbc library. **This allows integrated security to be used.** It
>   does require additional binaries to deploy, but fortunately,
>   msnodesqlv8 is distributed with binaries for the most common
>   architectures

You are using integrated security, so you need to deal with that problem.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42794938/2224701).

Comment: Thanks! Hmm I am getting issue `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Trusted_Connection'` with your second snippet?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Try Integrated Security=SSPI;  instead of Trusted_Connection=True;. Or Trusted_Connection=yes;

Comment: Hmm, now I just get `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]`

Comment: Can you connect to `localhost\MSSQLSERVER01` using SSMS and Windows Authentication?  You should verify that, looks like it does not allow you to connect. [Check this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/).

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards But this is another problem which is not really connected with your original question.

Comment: I can connect fine in ssms, but not with sequelize?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Your web server probably running under system account. Either add that account to SQL logins or use sql authentication.

Comment: If I do a `whoami` in command prompt, I get `surface\george` which if I run `CREATE LOGIN [surface\george] FROM WINDOWS;` in my db, I get the error, `The server principal 'surface\george' already exists.`

Comment: The problém is not with your user account, but with the account you run your program, a web server I assume.

Comment: Oh I see, I am using an express on nodejs, running sequelize. How would I find out the account that is running with?

Comment: No idea, depends on how do you launch it. Check `services.msc` if it's there.

Comment: But more usual is to use SQL authentication for a web server, not integrated windows authentication.

Comment: This for my development, I use SQL auth for my remote (and prod) enviroments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940406/logging-into-local-sql-server-instance-with-windows-auth?noredirect=1#comment78847004_45940406) question - we think maybe sequelize doesn't support this?

Comment: sequelize-msnodesqlv8 should supprt SQL connection with integrated authentication. Standart Sequelize does not support it.

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to get either to support it