# Sequelize and peer authentication for Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My `postgres` database has been set up to use peer authentication and I am not sure how to tell Sequelize to use this method?

Currently we are using the following:

```
new Sequelize("postgres://127.0.0.1/dbname", {});
```

I also tried the following which did not work

```
new Sequelize("postgresql:///dbname?host=/var/lib/postgresql");
```

In both cases I get the error:

```
SequelizeBaseError: password authentication failed for user"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

A bit more exploration shows the following will do the job:

```
new Sequelize('mydb', undefined, undefined, {
     host: '/var/run/postgresql',
     dialect: 'postgres'
   });
```

The actual connection is handled by the package 'pg' and this was documented in an [issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/613).

Note, I have tested this to work with pg@6.4.1 and sequelize@4.4.2.