# sequelize - not able to make connection with MSSQL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to setup connection with MS SQL but for some reason, sequelize is not able to pass the hostname correctly, Instead of pass 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' it pass 'localhostSQLEXPRESS'. Any idea where to fix it ?

```
'use strict';
const _ = require('lodash');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'db_user', 'db_user', {
    host: 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    },
});
// define model 
var batchDetails = sequelize.define('batchDetails', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field:'id',
        primaryKey: true
    },
    batch_no: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field:'batch_no',
    },
    date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field:'date',
    }
})

batchDetails.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
    // Table created
    return User.batchDetails({
      id: 1,
      batch_no: 'CASFR342'
    });
  });
```

error log:-

> sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please
>   use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at
>   http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
>   node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:242:13 tedious deprecated The
>   default value for `options.encrypt` will change from `false` to
>   `true`. Please pass `false` explicitly if you want to retain current
>   behaviour.
>   node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:69:26
>   Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to
>   localhostSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhostSQLEXPRESS
>       at Connection.connection.on.err (C:\Node JS Workspace\db\node_modules\DB\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:97:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Connection.socketError (C:\Node JS Workspace\db\node_modules\DB\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1016:14)
>       at C:\Node JS Workspace\db\node_modules\DB\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:861:25
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (C:\Node JS Workspace\db\node_modules\DB\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:69:18)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:104:17)

Comment: I think I was // but I am still not able to connect.                                               

Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost\SQLEXPRESS
    at Connection.connection.on.err (C:\Node JS

Comment: This should help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903574/connect-to-a-local-sql-server-db-with-sequelize

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works on my local sql server express:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'db_user', 'db_pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
     options: { instanceName: "sqlexpress" }
   }
});
```

The trick was in the `dialectOptions.instanceName` property.

Comment: I was struggle to make it works.
And this trick is works for me, "sqlexpress" should be place on instanceName.
Wonder why none mention about this.

Answer (score 0):

Update your host path.

- Before: `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`
- After: `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`