# Having troubles connecting sequelize with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, orm, sequelize.js

I'm experiencing some stupid problem while connecting sequelize with SQL Server and the error that is thrown looks something like this :

> (node:13096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:    SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> at ConnectionManager.connect (E:\ProgramFiles\MojeVjezbe\sidejob_test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:138:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async ConnectionManager._connect (E:\ProgramFiles\MojeVjezbe\sidejob_test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
> at async E:\ProgramFiles\MojeVjezbe\sidejob_test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
> at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (E:\ProgramFiles\MojeVjezbe\sidejob_test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)

Here is my configuration for sequelize code :

```
module.exports = {
  //host: "localhost",
  database: "testdb",
  //server : 'localhost',
  dialectModulePath: 'sequelize-msnodesqlv8',
  dialect: "mssql",
  port : 1433,
  dialectOptions : {
    //encrypt: true,
    InstanceName : "MSSQLSERVER",
    //connectionString : 'Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
  },
    pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
    }
};
```

As you can see I've tried changing connection string, host, server but the error is still the same. I've also tried enabling TCP/IP for SQL Server and it hasn't worked either.

What am I missing? I don't have a username nor password so I don't think it may be a problem in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to a local SQL Server db with sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903574/connect-to-a-local-sql-server-db-with-sequelize)

Comment: Tried this one and it wasn't helpful

Comment: And that comment is not helpful either. So step back. Can you connect to localhost using SSMS or some other db-aware program (bcp, sqlcmd, dbreaver, etc.)?

Comment: FWIW MSSQLSERVER is the name of the default instance - you shouldn't use that in your connection information. You connect to the default instance using just the machine name (or localhost, etc.). For any server instance (default or named), either use the correct name only or use machine name and port - not both.

Comment: You seem to be right because I've tried leaving only connection string for database connection but now there is another error that states smth like failed to login user ''